# Command for exporting MS Access Database to Mysql

Tags: mysql, ms-access, export

Is there any command to export `Access Database` table to `MySQL` using command line.

i know we can do it manually. but i want to do it automatic on specific schedule. so if any command will there than we can do it using command line.

Once we done with it we can create batch file and we schedule it.

Can any one suggest me which one is best.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data Import feature (MS Access format) in [dbForge Studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Command line is supported for Data Import. Just create import template file and use it in your schedule task. Try trial version).

Comment: thank you for your response.i just want to know is it possible to export one table data as a .sql file using command line?

Comment: Yes of course, it is possible too. See Backup or Data Export feature. The command line is supported.